# Why am I getting a 404 error when connecting to a specific webpage using Jsoup?

Tags: java, dom, http-status-code-404, jsoup, connect

I'm trying to get some video game data from Metacritic and I keep on getting a 404 error on this webpage:

```
http://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-2/ico
```

The connect command is very basic:

```
Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36").timeout(0).get();
```

Out of the hundreds of similar video game webpages on Metacritic I've tried connecting to, that's the only one that returns the 404 every time. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Chrome or [httpie.](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie)

Comment: Same here. When I enter the URL into a browser, it works fine. But when I try connecting to it using Jsoup, it gives me a 404.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server is returning a 404.

```
$ curl -I http://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-2/ico
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Apache
X-Varnish: 868026494
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 15:26:21 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

The fact that it *also* returns non-404-looking content doesn't affect Jsoup; it's just looking at the code the server gives in the HTTP-header.

Welcome to the craptastic "how does anything work?!" world of the internets. :) Interestingly, `curl -I http://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-2/SDKFJSDF` returns an HTTP-header code of `200 OK` yet displays a page whose content says 404. Did I mention the internets is full of crap?

You can ignore these errors by invoking [`ignoreHttpErrors(true)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Request.html#ignoreHttpErrors%28boolean%29) on the `Connection.Request` object.

Comment: Whoever made the site (or that page) is playing a joke.

Comment: How do I fix this? :(

Comment: I just discovers it happens with the following page too: http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/tropico --- could you confirm?

Comment: Yup (well, first it gives a 301-redirect to `http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/tropico`, but that then 404's). I'll update my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is pretty late for your question, but I encountered this today and finally realize where Metacritic screwed up. It looks like they have an apache configuration to provide 404 errors whenever an *ico file (or most images) is requested. They likely have something like this set up:

`RewriteRule (js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|xml)$ - [R=404,L,NC]]`

And they're missing a period before those extensions. Thus, anything that ends in those words, *even if they're part of the game name*, are returning 404s with content. Proof:

```
$ curl -I -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla...' 'http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/foojpg'
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

$ curl -I -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla...' 'http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/foojpgz'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

$ curl -I -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla...' 'http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/fooxml'
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

$ curl -I -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla...' 'http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/foocss'
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

$ curl -I -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla...' 'http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/foojs'
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

$ curl -I -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla...' 'http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/fooico'
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

$ curl -I -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla...' 'http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/fooicoo'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Which I find kind of amusing :) Anyway, mystery solved.